# swf customize order of symbol class

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

In a flash project, I'm embedding images into SWF using actionscript code.
To generate SWF from action script, I'm using "mxmlc" for compilation.
But now the problem with the symbol class. When viewed swf with swfdump, the order in which the resources are embedded into the code are different each time when the class/constructor name changes.
Is there any way to customize the order of symbol class name.

Order should be as follows when views in swfdump:

```
[04c]       174 SYMBOLCLASS
                exports 0001 as "swffile_img0"
                exports 0003 as "swffile_img2"
                exports 0002 as "swffile_img6"
                exports 0006 as "swffile_img5"
                exports 0005 as "swffile_img1"
                exports 0004 as "swffile_embeddedXML"
                exports 0007 as "swffile_img4"
                exports 0009 as "swffile_img3"
                exports 0008 as "swffile_img7"
```

Comment: Why is it so important to order what you see in swfdump?

Comment: Images need to be extracted from the resultant SWF if required by the following levels. As actionscript compilation procedure is in batch mode for all the assets given, it is required to have the same output consistent across all the swf files (output as shown above using swfdump).